# Multiple items selection in an Android ListView with custom view

Tags: android, android-listview, multipleselection, android-actionmode

I am trying to implement in an Android application a multiple items selection in an Android `ListView` to allow the user to delete severals rows in one action with the help of the action mode.

For example, I check the first item listening to the long click (in the following example, `contacts` is a `ListView`) :

```
@override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
  contacts.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
  contacts.setItemChecked(position, true);

  return true;
}
```

The matter is that after calling the `setItemChecked()` method, `getCheckedItemPositions()` method return `null` but it should return the position of the item that has been checked into the `onItemLongClick()` method no ?

The items of my `ListView` are made with a custom view. So I read all over the internet that my custom view have to implement the `Checkable` interface. So here the main container of my custom view :

```
public final class CheckableLinearLayout
    extends LinearLayout
    implements Checkable
{

  private boolean checked;

  public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isChecked()
  {
    return checked;
  }

  @Override
  public void setChecked(boolean checked)
  {
    this.checked = checked;
  }

  @Override
  public void toggle()
  {
    checked = !checked;
  }

}
```

and here the layout of an item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.package.CheckableLinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="10dip"
  android:background="@drawable/bg_contact"
>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contactPhoto"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
  />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
  />
</com.package.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

I hope that someone will be able to help me !

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

The original `onItemLongClick` method is this one :

```
@Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  {
    if (actionMode != null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    contacts.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    contacts.setItemChecked(position, true);
    getActionBarActivity().startSupportActionMode(new ActionModeCallback());

    return true;
  }
```

And I called the `getCheckedItemPositions()` method into a method of my action mode class.

If I rewrite the previous method putting the `getActionBarActivity().startSupportActionMode(new ActionModeCallback());` before setting the choice mode, it seems to work :)

```
@Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  {
    if (actionMode != null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    getActionBarActivity().startSupportActionMode(new ActionModeCallback());
    contacts.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    contacts.setItemChecked(position, true);

    return true;
  }
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `setItemChecked()` manually.

Just setup the ListView (previously) with

```
contacts.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
contacts.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() { ... });
```

And when you long-press an item, it will be checked automatically (and `onCreateActionMode()` will be invoked for the choice mode listener).

Comment: Thk you for you help ! I have updated my original post with newer information !

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the current problem. Please trim your question a bit (or better yet, if it's a _different_ problem, ask another one).

Comment: I added the answer to the post and I'm going to create a new question for the other subject. Thk you :)